# Symfony 5 throwing Access Denied Exception

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

I am trying to use multiple authenticators (for each user role). They were working fine until the last one, which redirects unauthenticated users to URL `/dashboard/` to login, but requests to `/dashboard` are thrown `AccessDeniedHttpException`:

[image]

This is my `security.yaml` file, which have all the firewalls:

```yaml
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha512

    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/admin/
            anonymous: lazy
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\AdminAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: admin_logout
        expert:
            pattern: ^/dashboard/
            anonymous: lazy
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\ExpertAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: expert_logout
        user:
            anonymous: lazy
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\UserAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: user_logout

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

        - { path: ^/ask, roles: ROLE_USER }

        - { path: ^/dashboard/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/dashboard, roles: ROLE_EXPERT }
```

I think it is not necessary to paste here the authenticator since it is the Symfony 5 `make:auth` maker command default which I copied and pasted for all the three authenticators while changing only `public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'user_login';` and `onAuthenticationSuccess()` function's redirect response path.

I also used the default `SecurityController`:

```php
namespace App\Controller\Expert;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

/**
 * Class SecurityController
 * @package App\Controller\Expert
 * @Route("/dashboard")
 */
class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="expert_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        if ($this->getUser()) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('expert_index');
        }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('expert/security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="expert_logout")
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        $this->addFlash('success', 'Session closed');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('expert_index');
    }
}
```

Whenever I access to `/admin`, `/admin/whatever` or `/ask`, `/ask/whatever` I am redirected to its respective login form (`/admin/login` and `/ask/dashboard`).

I can access directly to `/dashboard/login` if I am not logged from another authenticator or if I am logged with `ROLE_EXPERT`. If not, I am getting the mentioned exception.

Well, do you see what is going on?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the trailing slash in "pattern: ^/dashboard/"?

Comment: @Vyctorya, nope, I didn't, I thought it was kind of part of the regular expression, what seems it isn't. That may worked... Write an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move `- { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }` as last `access_control` entry.

That's because Symfony parses it as you're writing it (think about it like it's a FIFO queue) and, as `/` could be accessed in anonymous way, associated token will be anonymous (it won't try to read from session or whatever).

Comment: Now, if I go to `/dashboard/` I am redirected to `/dashboard/login` (`expert` firewall) but if I go to `/dashboard` I am redirected to `/login` (`user` firewall)...

Comment: @Maramal what would you expect from `/dashboard`?

Comment: @Maramal maybe `expert` and `main` firewalls, should not have the trailing slash.

Comment: Yes, that is what @Vyctorya said. It is working thanks to I removed the trailing slash of those firewalls.